# systemd.networkd: how to set default link-local address?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd, avahi

systemd-networkd: Is it possible to configure default link-local address, which will be tried as the first one? Something like '--start=' parameter for avahi-autoipd.

Comment: It doesn't look like that's supported, no. Not sure if there are plans for it either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of systemd v252-stable you can do IPv4LLStartAddress=169.254.1.1 Something like

```
[Match]
Name=en* eth*
KernelCommandLine=!nfsroot

[Network]
DHCP=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=fallback
IPv4LLStartAddress=169.254.1.1

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10
ClientIdentifier=mac

[DHCPv4]
MaxAttempts=3
```

Would allow for a network interface that gets DHCP but will use a link local address starting at 169.254.1.1 if DHCP is not available. It will figure out a new address if conflicts occur.